# Enviar Header de outro domínio em php

Tags: php, header

Galera, tenho um site parceiro, que necessitaria enviar suas informações para o navegador do cliente assim que o cliente acessasse meu site, eu faço isso atualmente com iframe e pixel, mas seria muito bom se fosse possível fazer isso de um modo automático diretamente quando acessassem o meu site, logo que iframe carrega toda pagina e deixa a minha mais lenta. Pelo que pesquisei acho que não é possível isso em php, mas não custa perguntar a quem entende mais que eu (que não é difícil) rs...
Mesmo que não seja possível via header, qualquer dica será bem vinda! ;)
de toda forma, obrigado!

Comment: Você não poderia fazer isso com um web service, e consumir com ajax?

Comment: Não havia pensado nisso, vou pesquisar sobre, obrigado.